# Parser Error Message: Code blocks are not allowed in this file

Tags: sharepoint-designer, 2007, pages

I am getting this error:

> Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Code blocks are not allowed in this file.

Source Error:

```
Line 61:                   <div class="webpart-block last">
Line 62:                <div class="floatleft news-listing-image">                                
Line 63:                    <%# GetImageColumn(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "PublishingRollupImage"))%></div>  // Here is the Error
Line 64:                <div class="floatleft">
Line 65:                            <h3 class="webpart-title" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="javascript:ShowNewsArticle('<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Path") %>');">
```

Source File: /_catalogs/masterpage/IndexQNewsArchive.aspx    Line: 63

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint disables the ability to create server-side script by default, you have to turn it on. You do that in the web.config file, in the `configuration/SharePoint/PageParserPaths` configuration section:

```
<PageParserPaths>
    <PageParserPath VirtualPath="/_catalogs/masterpage/IndexQNewsArchive.aspx" CompilationMode="Always" AllowServerSideScript="true" />
</PageParserPaths>
```

Comment: I have added the above code in web.config and now i am getting this error: The control with ID 'ModalPopupExtender' requires a ScriptManager on the page. The ScriptManager must appear before any controls that need it. 
Any idea how to add this ScriptManager?

Comment: Add `<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>` after the `<body>` tag in master page.